# deploy .net framework 4.8 legacy app to azure container

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, containers, devops

I was wondering if it’s possible to deploy a legacy .net 4.8 web app to an azure container/docker

The application would need migrating to .net 5/6 framework eventually but going through that would require time. It require a swot analysis/investigation.

In the short term I was wondering if it can be deployed in an azure container. This would significantly take the application forward in terms of possibly using a pipeline CI/CD to deploy.

Also, Not done massive research into this but is it possible to deploy an app using 4.8 using a pipeline? I’m currently using TC/octopus for CI/CD to deploy to azure. This is old legacy process / code though.

Any thoughts? / advice? TIA

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any technical issues deploying your application on an Azure container service. You can probably start with [Azure App Service for containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-custom-container?pivots=container-linux&tabs=azure-cli) which will provide a lot of CI/CD facilities, but other container services can do the job.

My advice would be to put your container in a private network without using Azure Private Link to mitigate security issues with the .net version.

Comment: Thankyou. Not done massive research into this but is it possible to deploy an app using 4.8 using a pipeline? I’m currently using TC/octopus for CI/CD to deploy to azure. This is old legacy process / code though.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the .Net framework, but if you can create the image, you can deploy it via a pipeline. The App Service will work directly with the image without knowing anything about your .NET version.

Comment: I'm not familiar with TC/octopus, but what you can probably do is push the image to an Azure Registry and then set up a webhook to automatically update your App Service. Depending on your use case, this may be enough. 
Ex: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/deploy-run-container-app-service/